# Stripe Prebuilt hosted checkout works well in localhost but not working in live server (400 Bad Request))

Tags: stripe-payments

**I have tested with Test keys and Live keys in localhost, everything works fine**. However, when I upload to server , it doesn't work and the error message are the following :

**Error message**

[image]

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
    (index):49 Error: IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
        at new r (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:6143)
        at zs (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:161250)
        at Gs (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:161546)
        at https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:162448
        at Ws (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:162459)
        at Js (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:162965)
        at hc.redirectToCheckout (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:183411)
        at mydomain.com/test/:38:25
    (anonymous) @ (index):49
    m.stripe.network/inner.html#url=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Ftest%2F&title=Buy%20cool%20new%20product&referrer=&muid=76e3da6d-3258-4e69-9eab-4b090df223530e1418&sid=NA&version=6&preview=false:1 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
    Promise.then (async)
    f @ inner.html:1
    t.b @ inner.html:1
    onMessage @ inner.html:1
```

Here are the 2 files copy directly from Stripe official docs

```
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder
```

**index.php**

```
  <button id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
      
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51HmrX2IxP40eGXqz3tWsmlkfw11otNk5U6DDiaDvejfYd33oFZCE13zvp2nRbPUweGMbkVEmfUQYzPho9uI8odHk009iU4cFjG");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("create-session.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

**create-session.php**

```
    require 'vendor/init.php';
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51HmrX2IxP40eGXqzRwJ6ObqPSvqZcXYRtJDxAsFqru1a2kFzas9tBfZH9UkEYHHwdFRVIRgS2bmsmqiwtDDmMbD70zy0SFFarz');

    $response = array( 
        'status' => 0, 
        'error' => array( 
            'message' => 'Invalid Request!'    
        ) 
    ); 
     
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
        $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
        $request = json_decode($input);     
    } 
     
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
        http_response_code(400); 
        echo json_encode($response); 
        exit; 
    } 

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $YOUR_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com';
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'unit_amount' => 2000,
          'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
            'images' => ["http://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
          ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.php',
    ]);

    echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
```

I have upload the files to 2 different websites to test and still meet Error 400 (Bad Request) ... Anyone can help and advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your server-side logs, as most likely you are not returning the JSON you think you are.  You could also `console.log()` the value of `session` to confirm/refute it is in fact what you're expecting.

Comment: I remove this part of coding and the error is gone 

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
        http_response_code(400); 
        echo json_encode($response); 
        exit; 
    }

Comment: So now it works?  Or does that just stop the JSON parse error from causing a 400 error?

Comment: the error still there.... just that i remove that part of coding so that the program works for now...